# Different methods of running flask app and setting environment

Tags: python, flask

I have the following app which when I run using

```
flask run
```

seems to execute without error but when I perform `python app.py` gives me the following error:

```
➣ $ python app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "/Users/pkaramol/Workspace/second_flask/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import JWT, jwt_required
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import settings
from resources.item import Item, ItemList

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')
app.secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting flask app...")
    print(os.end['SECRET_KEY'])
    db.create_all()
    api.add_resource(Item, '/item/<string:name>')
    api.add_resource(ItemList, '/items')
```

What is the difference in the two ways of running the `flask` app and why in the second case the environment is not rendered appropriately?

I am using `python-dotenv` to inject env vars from `.env` file
btw in the first case where the app starts without errors, I do not see the `print` statement I use for debug.

and if in the case of `flask run` the code below `if __name__ == '__main__'` is not called, how will I initialise my db by calling `db.create_all()`?

Comment: `app.secret_key = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY", os.urandom(24) )` get secret if not found useing `os.urandom(24)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `app.secret_key` assignment with arbitrary string.